# SQLAlchemy with Python 3.2: C extensions are not supported?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I've installed SQLAlchemy under Python 3.2.2 and saw e message in command prompt:

```
C extensions are not supported on this Python platform, speedups are not enabled.
Plain-Python build succeeded.
```

But in [docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/_sources/intro.txt):

```
The C extensions as well as Python 3 builds are supported.
```

How could it be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

English ambiguity.

{The C extensions} and {Python 3 builds} individually are supported.

{The C extensions and Python 3 builds} together are not supported:

Later in the doc:

> Currently, the extensions are only supported on the 2.xx series of cPython, not Python 3 or Pypy

Comment: patch for py3k support is at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2161.   Basically we need someone proficient in Python C extensions to sign off on that patch and Taavi's comment.    Then it's ready to go.

Comment: @zzzeek any estimate of when it might be done?  seems to have been stalled for 6 months...

Comment: well the patch is there, needs to be reconciled with some recent changes and fixes, then there's just some C idioms I need someone to go over and let me know that they're correct.  its straightforward work that anyone who works with Python C extensions could handle.

Comment: I would also like to see this implemented. Because the ticket has not been updated in 11 months (!), I'm nervous about committing to SQLAlchemy for our group. A response from @pjenvey or zzzeek would be very welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

---

WARNING: C extensions are not supported on this Python platform, speedups are not enabled.
Plain-Python build succeeded.

---

The patch was written before Dec 25 '11 and it's still not implemented almost 2 years later.... boo hiss!